# Generate SQL scripts in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, scripting, ssms

I am generating table, view, stored procedure scripts from SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

The options that are set to true are

1. Check for object existence.
2. Check for dependent objects.
3. One file per script.

The objects are being generated in alphabetical order.  Is there a way for me to generate the scripts in order of relation, so that when I run the scripts one by one, I will not have key missing errors or object missing errors?

In simple words, I want the scripts to be generated in dependency order, rather than alphabetical order. Is there a way to do it using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: What u have done so far ? show something so we can improve it or solve the problem you r facing.

Comment: I have generated the scripts. I created an another database and now I am trying to run the "table" scripts  one by one. The scripts are erroring out because they are generated in alphabetical order, which is not the order we want to created the tables. So is there a way for me to know the order in which I can create the tables so that I wont encounter any errors.

Answer (score -2):

You can choose to script the entire database by doing the following.

1. Right click on you already created database.
2. Click on "Task>Generate Scripts..."
3. On the "Choose Objects" screen select "Script Entire Database and all database objects", as shown below.
4. Follow the next steps to save or copy to clip board.

This should script all your tables into one script in dependency order.

[image: Script generator]

If that still hasn't worked then I suggest you simply reorder your script.

Comment: This is what I am doing but the objects are being generated in alphabetical order instead of dependency order.